# Page taking too long to load

Tags: php

I find it very difficult to comprehend why one of my pages is taking long before displaying its content. The code on the page is as follows.

Please, advise what could be wrong and if the code is secure. If not how to fix it.

```
<?php

//open database
    include("includes/db_connect.php");
//require("includes/mysql_conn.php");

    // Check to see if the type of file uploaded is a valid image type .........................
function is_valid_type($file)
{
    // This is an array that holds all the valid image MIME types
    // These are the same for all file upload boxes
    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif");

    // This is an array that holds all valid image extensions
    // These are the same for all file upload boxes
    $valid_exts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'gif');

    // This check is optional
    if(!in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
        return 0;

    // Get the extension from the uploaded filename
    $upload_ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // This check is essential for security
    if(!in_array($upload_ext, $valid_exts))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}  
//...................................................................................................    
    // Just a short function that prints out the contents of an array in a manner that's easy to read
    // I used this function during debugging but it serves no purpose at run time for this example
    function showContents($array)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    // Set some constants

    // This variable is the path to the image folder where all the images are going to be stored
    // Note that there is a trailing forward slash
    $TARGET_PATH = "images/";

    // Get our POSTed variables
    $ctitle = $_POST['ctitle'];
    $csubject = $_POST['csubject'];
    $creference = $_POST['creference'];
    $cyear = $_POST['cyear'];
    $cobjecttype = $_POST['cobjecttype'];
    $cmaterial = $_POST['cmaterial'];
    $ctechnic = $_POST['ctechnic'];
    $cwidth = $_POST['cwidth'];
    $cheight = $_POST['cheight'];
    $cperiod = $_POST['cperiod'];
    $cmarkings = $_POST['cmarkings'];
    $cdescription = $_POST['cdescription'];
    $csource = $_POST['csource'];
    $cartist = $_POST['cartist'];
    $image = $_FILES['image'];

// Build our target path full string. This is where the file will be moved do
// i.e. images/picture.jpg
$target_path_1 = $TARGET_PATH . $image['name'];

    // Sanitize our inputs
    $ctitle = mysql_real_escape_string($ctitle);
    $csubject= mysql_real_escape_string($csubject);
    $creference = mysql_real_escape_string($creference);
    $cyear = mysql_real_escape_string($cyear);
    $cobjecttype = mysql_real_escape_string($cobjecttype);
    $cmaterial = mysql_real_escape_string($cmaterial);  
    $ctechnic = mysql_real_escape_string($ctechnic);
    $cwidth = mysql_real_escape_string($cwidth);    
    $cheight = mysql_real_escape_string($cheight);
    $cperiod = mysql_real_escape_string($cperiod);
    $cmarkings = mysql_real_escape_string($cmarkings);  
    $cdescription = mysql_real_escape_string($cdescription);
    $csource = mysql_real_escape_string($csource);
    $cartist = mysql_real_escape_string($cartist);
    $image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

    // Make sure all the fields from the form have inputs
    if ( $ctitle == "" || $csubject == "" || $creference == "" || $cyear == "" || $cobjecttype == "" || $cmaterial == "" || $ctechnic == "" || $cwidth == "" || $cheight == "" || $cperiod == "" || $cmarkings == "" || $cdescription == "" || $csource == "" || $cartist == "" || $image['name'] == "")
    {
        echo "All fields are required";

        exit;
    }

// Check to make sure that our file is actually an image
// You check the file type instead of the extension because the extension can easily be faked
if (!is_valid_type($image))
{
         echo "You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";

         exit;
}  

// Here we check to see if a file with that name already exists
// You could get past filename problems by appending a timestamp to the filename and then continuing
if (file_exists($target_path_1))
{
        echo "A file with that name already exists";

        exit;
}  

// Lets attempt to move the file from its temporary directory to its new home
if (
    move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $target_path_1)
)
{
         // NOTE: This is where a lot of people make mistakes.
         // We are *not* putting the image into the database; we are putting a reference to the file's location on the server
         $sql = "insert into collections (ctitle, csubject, creference, cyear, cobjecttype, cmaterial, ctechnic, cwidth, cheight, cperiod, cmarkings, cdescription, csource, cartist, cfilename) values ('$ctitle', '$csubject', '$creference', '$cyear', '$cobjecttype', '$cmaterial', '$ctechnic', '$cwidth', '$cheight', '$cperiod', '$cmarkings', '$cdescription', '$csource', '$cartist', '" . $image['name'] . "')";
         $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DataBase: " . mysql_error());

         exit;
}
else
{
         // A common cause of file moving failures is because of bad permissions on the directory attempting to be written to
         // Make sure you chmod the directory to be writeable

       echo "Could not upload file. Check read/write persmissions on the directory";

         exit;
}  
    ?>
```

And my database connection code:

```
<?php
//set connection variables
$host = "localhost";
$username = "joseph";
$password = "";
$db_name = "collectionsdb"; //database name

//connect to mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

//check if any connection error was encountered
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Thanx.

Joseph

Comment: There is no question here, I think it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: on way to see where the problem lies would be to comment out the connection include as well as the mysql_query() function and see if the problem persists. If this is the case then I copy paste the connection include as well please.

Comment: or are you uploading the image while testing the code? what size of file are you uploading? if your using google chrome the upload progress will be displayed in the bottom left corner, once thats finished it will run the code etc... try it with various size files, to check the difference's

Comment: There should be no question with your PHP code. Check if the header is too big (e.g. POST content too long) as @Marty said, and check DNS lookup time and other HTTP relative questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fine to me.

There are three stages.

- Time to upload the data(depends on filesize and connection speed)
- connect to the database(depends on the load on your database server)
- and the moving of the file on the server(depends on the load of your server) ...

If you are on a local test system there could be the virus scan interfering as well. First filtering the post data then scanning the file and scanning the file again when moved(yes, they can be pretty paranoid...).

Advice: Put some "print_r(microtime());" in there and take a look.

Comment: Yes, I am testing on a local system and the slow loading happens at the stage of accessing the page before any file uploading. Thanx for your ticks. I will take further look into it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not necessarily secure. Sql injection is on thing that I is easily spotted. Do not pass the variables into the query string like that. Although you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()` there are scenarios where this is not adequate.

Please use parametrized queries. Also you should worry about html markup inserted into your db that could be used for XSS.

Another point to keep in mind is the permissions for you upload folder. Make sure you don't have everyone read and write.

Hope it helps.

See my comment for additional info about the root cause of your slow loads.